# Writing date and IP to file ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I've been trying to write the date and my local IP to a file in ubuntu with a cron job. This is what I have tried:

```
echo date >> /home/ccpadmin/dls/ip.txt | echo ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}' >> /home/ccpadmin/dls/ip.txt | echo "\r\n" >> /home/ccpadmin/dls/ip.txt
```

But the newlines don't work, and it doesn't have the date in the file. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "$(date) $(ip addr list eth0 | \
                awk -F'[ /]+' '$2=="inet"{print $3}')" >> your_file
```

`ip` output is marginally easier to parse than `ifconfig`. If you want to log more things, it will get pretty messy pretty fast this way. Consider getting your data into variables, then formatting your output:

```
log_file=...
log_date="$(date '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')"
log_ip="$(ip addr list eth0 | awk -F'[ /]+' '$2=="inet"{print $3}')"
log_...=...

echo "$log_date $log_ip $log..." >> "$log_file"
```

Comment: I tried this in an sh file and it tells me that there's no such file or directory

Comment: The one with the variables.

Comment: That's usually a simple syntax error or such. Having spaces around the `=` signs for instance can do strange things like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -n $(date) >> /home/ccpadmin/dls/ip.txt ; echo -n " " >> /home/ccpadmin/dls/ip.txt ; echo  `ifconfig eth0 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}'|sed 's/addr://'` >> /home/ccpadmin/dls/ip.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't write the IP

Comment: Probably need to ifconfig and make sure you have eth0 with an ip address assigned.  I tested this on ubuntu 14.04 and output file has one line with the date and one line with my ip.

Comment: That edit helped. The only problem now is the lack of spacing and newlines. "\r\n" Doesn't work here, right?

Comment: Let me know what the output you want exactly and I can probably help with that.  I just assumed 2 lines in a file with one being the date and one the ip.

Comment: I just want a new line in between each entry. so "<date> <IP> <newline> <date> <IP>"

Comment: I updated so each line has {date} <space> {ip} <newline>.  Then starts same on next line.  I'm sure there is a more efficient way and you can clean it up but it should get you going.